# Can I change a component I downloaded in react-native project from node_modules?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, node-modules, react-native-picker

I want to use a kinda outdated module react-native-numbers-please (last update 2 years ago), but it doesn't work. I think it's because it uses a Picker from react-native. I've changed that in the module's **NumbersPlease.tsx** which is the main file from which the component is exported.

So I've updated it to use Picker from @react-native-picker/picker as react suggested in a warning message, but I don't think its changed anything since I still get the exact same warning (Picker has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release...).

I've tried restarting the npm server, but It hasn't changed anything.

Is there something else I need to do for react-native to recognize that I've changed the module, or does it just simply not work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A warning message should not keep your project from building/running. Please provide a description of what you mean when you state that "it doesn't work"

Comment: @BaconPancakes Thanks for the response! It would only display a down arrow, like the one that should appear in a picker, but pressing on it didn't do anything, as if the picker had no items. Anyways, I've just decided to use @vseslav/react-native-horizontal-picker instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
npm uninstall packName
npm install packageName
```

then start your project

Make sure server is off by the time you are running this command.

if it does not work  reset-cache
try starting it with
`npm start` -- --reset-cache
`expo r -c`  ///if u are using expo

Answer (score 0):

You can start editing it inside `node_modules` folder and then patching the package. Then you need to run the following command to patch the package:

```sh
npm install -g patch-package
patch-package <module name>
```

This will create a folder at the root of the project called `patches`. Then in your `package.json` file under scripts add the following script:

```json
"scripts": {
    ....
   "postinstall": "patch-package"
}
```

From now on, when you run install, it will also apply patches on original files.